# How do I send an activity's layout to a non activity class to change an imageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, imageview

so I'm trying to send a layout that has an imageview that I want to replace with an image picked by the user, then send that whole layout to a new activity to be displayed but I'm having trouble. It's returning null at the line below where I indicated. Please help!

So this is the class that recieves the layout and changes the image of the imageView.

```
public class TestingClass
{

    public static int displayImage(Activity activity, int id, String path)
    {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(id);//This is where it's returning null
        img.setImageBitmap(BitmapUtility.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(path,500,500));
        return id;
    }
}
```

Then displayImage will be called in this activity.

```
public class UserCard extends Activity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_card);

    }


    public int sendstuff()
    {
        String testing2 = cardFactory.getInstance().getValue().grabImagePathString;//Getting the image path the user selected
        return TestingClass.displayImage(this,R.layout.user_card,testing2);
    }
```

Finally, I want that layout (with the ImageView changed by the user) in my main layout.

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)//Does Load METHODS in order!!!!
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    UserCard user = new UserCard();
    al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add("max");
     arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, user.sendstuff(), R.id.helloText, al);
    flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```

I also tried it this way, but the line below is always being null!!!I don't know why?!?!

```
public class UserCard extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item);


    }

    public int displayImage(String path)
    {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maxCard);// THIS IS RETURNING NULL ALWAYLS ?!?!
        img.setImageBitmap(BitmapUtility.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(path,500,500));
        return R.layout.item;
    }

    public int sendstuff(String path)//In my other activity this is method i make an instance of, and I enter an image path string.
    {

        return displayImage(path);
    }
}
```

here's the xml

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:id="@+id/CardView">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="354dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/myCardFrame">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="254dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonQ"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:src="@drawable/max"/>
```

Comment: Could you just send the image view rather than the whole layout?

Comment: I need the whole layout for a particular purpose, there's an arrayadapter, which I didn't put, that needs a layout.

Comment: Sorry, yeah i did put the arrayadapter above, which takes in a layout

Comment: There's 2 problems. Switching the imageView's image with the image picked by the user. THEN, send that layout with the new image to the main activity.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code:

```
  return TestingClass.displayImage(this,R.layout.user_card,testing2);
```

to

```
return TestingClass.displayImage(this,R.id.nameOfYourView,testing2);
```

The R.layout is your whole activity view, to find a particular view inside of it you must use R.id.

For your particular case, you can create an interface or pass a list of Views too.

Comment: It's stil returning null :( @ ImageView img = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(id);

Answer (score 0):

On your create, assign your layout to a view and get the Id from the view

```
public class UserCard extends Activity {

View view;

 @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle  savedInstanceState) { 

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.user_card, null); 

 setContentView(view); 

} 

public int sendstuff() { 

String testing2 = cardFactory.getInstance().getValue().grabImagePathString;//Getting the image path the user selected return 
TestingClass.displayImage(view ,testing2);

 }
 }
```

You getting null pointer cause sendstuff doesn't know where to get R.layout.user_card

Change testing class to be like

```
public class TestingClass { 
public static int displayImage(View view, String path) { 
ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonQ);//This is where it's returning null         img.setImageBitmap(BitmapUtility.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(path,500,500));
 return id;
 } }
```

Comment: but view can't take in a layout it can only take in ids??

Comment: Even if the layout is a relativeLayout?

Comment: If it's relative layout, use relativelayout instead

Comment: It still gives me an error on,  view = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.user_card); It still expects an "id" instead of a layout

Comment: I don't think you can put in a layout resource in a view

Comment: Please refer to the modified answer. Pass in a view instead of the Id. You will get the image view id from the View.

Comment: but in onCreate the view can't take in a layout...it can only take id's , that won't solve a redline error :/

Comment: Please check how the View is created in the answer. I just tested this and it working fine

Comment: the only problem with using view, is in Testingclass, after you set the image to the view, you need to change the image, to the image the user has picked...

Comment: you cant do:   img.setImageBitmap(BitmapUtility.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(path,500,500));

Comment: what do you mean? and can you provide an example of that please?